# If $y_n \rightharpoonup y$ in $H$ and $|y_n|_H \leq C$ then $|y|_H \leq C$?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Suppose $y_n \rightharpoonup y$ in a Hilbert space $H$. Suppose $|y_n|_H \leq C$ uniformly. How do I show that $|y|_H \leq C$?

Not sure how to do it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By weak convergence we have $|y|_H^2=\langle y, y \rangle = \lim_{n\to \infty} \langle y_n, y\rangle$. By Cauchy-Schwarz $|\langle y_n, y \rangle| \leq C |y|_H$ and that finishes the proof.